# How to combine several events into RxJS to retrieve and filter data

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have several similar use cases where a table of data is shown. 
Next to the table there is an input field (searchLocal) for filtering the current data. Another input field (searchBackend) for filtering the data on the backend. And there is a refresh button.

```
<form class="form">
    <label>Local Search</label><input class="form-control" [formControl]="searchLocal">
    <label>Backend Search</label><input class="form-control" [formControl]="searchBackend">
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="wfRefresh()">Refresh</button>
</form>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let order of orders | async">
            {{order.id}} {{ order.customer_name}}
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I would like is the following:

- if searchLocal changed filter (local) previously retrieved data
- if searchBackend changed get data from backend with searchBackend and
  filter with searchLocal
- if refresh button is clicked get data from backend with searchBackend and filter with searchLocal (similar like searchBackend)

How can I accomplish this with RxJS? How can I combine the above three events? Is it maybe only solvable in steps?
Thanks for you help.

Next I have some non-working! code-snippets to give a rough idea of the functionality needed:

```
orders: Observable<Array<Order>>; // = new Subject<Array<Order>>();
searchLocal = new FormControl();
searchBackend = new FormControl();

constructor(
  private backendService: BackendService,
  private http: HttpClient
) { }

ngOnInit() {

  this.orders = this.searchLocal.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.getLocalOrders(term))
      .map(data => this.filter(data));

  // just for the idea
  this.orders = this.searchBackend.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(800)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.getOrders(term))
      .map(data => this.filter(data));
}

filter(data) {
  return data;
}

getLocalOrders(searchString: string): Observable<Array<Order>> {
  return localCopy; // ?
}

getOrders(searchString: string): Observable<Array<Order>> {
  return this.http.post<Array<Order>>('someurl', { filter: searchString });
}

wfRefresh() {
  //
}
```

Comment: you could try something with `combineLatest` operator

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511) can help you to find the best combining operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can achieve this conceptually:

```js
// This you already had
const frontendSearch$ = this.frontendSearch.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged();

// This you already had    
const backendSearch$ = this.backendSearch.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(800)
  .distinctUntilChanged();

// For example, refreshClicked$ could be a Subject on which
// you emit in the onClick handler.
const refresh$ = this.refreshClicked$
  .map(() => this.backendSearch.value);

const filteredOrders$ = Observable.combineLatest(
  // Merge events when changing the backendSearch text or
  // clicking the button
  Observable.merge(backendSearch$, refresh$)
    // Start with an empty search text to immediately start a search
    .startWith("")
    // … and use the value to get the orders from the backend
    .switchMap(value => this.getOrdersFromBackend(value)),
  // Also start the frontendSearch text with an initial value to
  // get going right away
  frontendSearch$.startWith("")
)
  // Now we just need to apply the frontend filtering
  .map(([orders, filterText]) => this.filterOrders(orders, filterText));
```

Comment: The above works fine. But when the http call fails >= 400, no further input from backendSearch or refresh is taken. Added a tap after refresh$ map, but is not reached. Disabled all my personal interceptors. Any idea?

Comment: An error ends an observable stream as per the observable contract. You can add a catch() to the http call and deal with it in whatever way you see fit to avoid that.

Comment: When the observable stream ends due to an error, I received the error in filteredOrders$.subscribe, but didn't got a complete message. Why didn't I got a complete message. Is this by design?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can read up on the observable contract on the rxjs website: http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html

Comment: Yes, it is. You can read up on the observable contract on the rxjs website: http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html

Comment: thx once again and solved all. I am using http interceptors and want to keep the angular backend service responsibility to only interprete API responses/errors and throw. The business components can than decide what to do in case of errors. It took me quite a long time to notice that a pipe/catchError (with Observable.of([]) after the switchMap moves the 'merge' stream to this new observable (losing the merge stream with the backendSearch$ and refresh$) and I needed to add this catch logic after the getOrdersFromBackend(). I hope my interpretation is right and choosed correct wording.

Comment: Yes, that is correct and why I said to add the catch to the HTTP call (directly), not down the chain. :-)